# Why is this limit $\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am confused about how we calculate this limit without L'Hopital rule.
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\tan(x)-\sin(x)}{x^3}$$
The steps I was able to do are
$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\tan(x)-\sin(x)}{x^3}=
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\tan(x)}{x^3}-\frac{\sin(x)}{x^3}=
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}=
\lim_{x\to0} 0 = 0
$$

However evaluating this limit using Wolfram Mathematica I get the result $\frac{1}{2}$.

I suspect the problem to be in the simplifications $\frac{\tan(x)}{x^3}\sim\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $\frac{\sin(x)}{x^3}\sim\frac{1}{x^2}$ but I don't understand how exactly.

Comment: You can use Taylor series, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517239/computing-limit-of-fracx-sin-xx-tan-x-without-lhôpital).

Comment: Thank you! But why are the steps I did wrong? I believe I haven't done anything illegal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Limit without l'Hopital](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3888365/understanding-limit-without-lhopital)

Comment: I don't understand your step $1/x^2-1/x^2$. This looks indeed "illegal".

Comment: Not really. I was able to solve the limit using other methods, but I was interested in why the steps in the question are actually wrong. Th answer you referenced is very useful still, thanks

Comment: You cannot add or substract equivalences $\sim$: for example, $x^{10}\sim x^{10}+1$ and $-x^{10}+1 \sim -x^{10}+2$ but $-1\not\sim 3$

Comment: @DietrichBurde I did that step because for all x in R - {0} that is defined as 0 as a sum of opposites, I believe

Comment: @Taladris Thank you, I think I see what I did wrong now

Comment: If $f_1 \sim g_1$ and $f_2 \sim g_2$, that does not mean that $f_1 + f_2 \sim g_1 + g_2$. Likewise for $f_1 - f_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspection is right: you cannot use equivalence in sum terms, only in a multiplicative terms. In this particular case, given $\tan x = x +\color{green} {o(x)}$, $\sin x = x +\color{red} {o(x)}$, you have different $o(x)$ in them, so you cannot just cancel them out.

Way to solve this can be factor $\sin x$ out and using equivalence $\sin x\sim x$, have

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\tan x - \sin x} {x^3} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\frac 1 {\cos x}- 1}{x^2} =   \lim_{x\to 0} \frac 1 {\cos x}  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {1-\cos x} {x^2} = \frac 1 2 
$$

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are bypassing an indeterminate form; in fact:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^3}=
\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\tan x}{x^3}-\dfrac{\sin x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1}{x^2}\left(\dfrac{\tan x}{x}-\dfrac{\sin x}{x} \right)$$
Now  $x^2 \to 0 \,$ and so does $\left(\dfrac{\tan x}{x}-\dfrac{\sin x}{x} \right)$; this is the problem.
Instead, using Taylor expansion and knowing that $\tan x \sim x+\dfrac{x^3}{3}$ and $\sin x \sim x-\dfrac{x^3}{6}$ you have:
$\dfrac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^3} \sim \dfrac{x^3}{2x^3}\to \dfrac{1}{2}\quad$ as $x \to 0$